# Substring and regex

Tags: javascript, regex, lodash

I have a SQL string:

```
var sql= "AND DT_FIM IS NULL AND ( CD_JOB, DT_INI_JOB ) IN  (SELECT x.CD_JOB, x.DT_INI FROM PRS_JOBS_MAQUINA x  WHERE x.CD_JOB = ':CD_JOB' AND TO_CHAR(x.DT_INI, 'YYYY-MM-DD') = ':DT_INI_JOB' AND x.DT_FIM IS NULL)
```

and i need to extract the binded values(:CD_JOB , :DT_INI_JOB), the problem is that with

```
var bindFields=sql.substring(sql.lastIndexOf("':") + 1 , sql.lastIndexOf("'"));
```

it returns only the first match and i need both.
Is it possible with Javascript? Lodash to the rescue if anybody find it useful.

https://jsfiddle.net/oq0dmyjo/1/ .
Apreciate your help . Thanks

Comment: Use [`var rex = /':([^']+)/g`](https://regex101.com/r/jN0xR5/1) and loop over the matches with `RegExp#exec` retrieving Group 1 values. (See *code generator* page for the JS code).

Comment: sorry , kind of newbie on this. Can you post an example.

Comment: I must leave, but I stayed a bit to post the answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a very simple regex with a capturing group:

```
/':([^']+)/g
```

**Explanation**:

- `':`  - a literal sequence `':`
- `([^']+)` - Group 1 capturing 1 or more symbols other than `'`
- `g`  -  a global modifier matching all instances.

Here are some resources to learn:

- [*Capturing groups*](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html)
- [*How do you access the matched groups in a JavaScript regular expression?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/432493/how-do-you-access-the-matched-groups-in-a-javascript-regular-expression)

JS code:

```js
var re = /':([^']+)/g; 
var str = "AND DT_FIM IS NULL AND ( CD_JOB, DT_INI_JOB ) IN  (SELECT x.CD_JOB, x.DT_INI FROM PRS_JOBS_MAQUINA x  WHERE x.CD_JOB = ':CD_JOB' AND TO_CHAR(x.DT_INI, 'YYYY-MM-DD') = ':DT_INI_JOB' AND x.DT_FIM IS NULL)";
var res = [];
while ((m = re.exec(str)) !== null) {
  res.push(m[1]);
}
document.body.innerHTML = "<pre>" + JSON.stringify(res, 0, 4) + "</pre>";
```

Comment: if i dont use the slash('\') , it trows an error.  Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :    i cannot change the string, it is hardcoded from server...

Comment: What do you mean? You do not need to escape any `'`

Comment: @LeonelMatiasDomingos He isn't telling you to change the string, he's just showing you how to parse it. The string isn't relevant. You can surround it in double quotes though just so you can demo it without errors.

Comment: @LeonelMatiasDomingos: your code is not valid JS here: `var str = 'AND DT_FIM IS NULL AND ( CD_JOB, DT_INI_JOB ) IN  (SELECT x.CD_JOB, x.DT_INI FROM PRS_JOBS_MAQUINA x  WHERE x.CD_JOB = ':CD_JOB' AND TO_CHAR(x.DT_INI, 'YYYY-MM-DD') = ':DT_INI_JOB' AND x.DT_FIM IS NULL)';`. You can't have it in your code. Fix it before applying any regex.

Answer (score 0):

Since it looks like you're binding the fields, you probably want to use `replace` with a replacement function. Use the regex from [@WiktorStribiżew](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38376754/5743988), `/':([^']+)'/g`, but then use it like this:

```js
var sql = "AND DT_FIM IS NULL AND ( CD_JOB, DT_INI_JOB ) IN  (SELECT x.CD_JOB, x.DT_INI FROM PRS_JOBS_MAQUINA x  WHERE x.CD_JOB = ':CD_JOB' AND TO_CHAR(x.DT_INI, 'YYYY-MM-DD') = ':DT_INI_JOB' AND x.DT_FIM IS NULL)";

var fields = {
    CD_JOB: 1,
    DT_INI_JOB: 2
};
sql = sql.replace(/':([^']+)'/g, function($0, $1) {
  return fields[$1];
});
console.log(sql);
```

Comment: this is perfect  @WiktorStribiżew,  but really need an array with the name of the binded fields.... it fine with var re = /':([^']+)/g; 
var str = "AND DT_FIM IS NULL AND ( CD_JOB, DT_INI_JOB ) IN  (SELECT x.CD_JOB, x.DT_INI FROM PRS_JOBS_MAQUINA x  WHERE x.CD_JOB = ':CD_JOB' AND TO_CHAR(x.DT_INI, 'YYYY-MM-DD') = ':DT_INI_JOB' AND x.DT_FIM IS NULL)";
var res = [];
while ((m = re.exec(str)) !== null) {
  res.push(m[1]);
}
document.body.innerHTML = "<pre>" + JSON.stringify(res, 0, 4) + "</pre>";

Comment: What are you using the array for?